# Unexpected behavior in Julia ifelse with isassigned

Tags: julia

```
test = [1, 1, 1, 1]
ifelse(isassigned(test, 5), test[5], "nope")
```

To me, this should yield the string "nope", but instead I get

```
BoundsError: attempt to access 4-element Array{Int64,1} at index [5]
```

Is this a bug or expected functionality?

For now, I am using

```
if isassigned(test, 5) test[5] else "nope" end
```

but this isn't very legible inside of a list comprehension.

Comment: for the particular usage, also try `get(test, 5, "nope")`

Comment: @张实唯 This is exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
julia> isassigned(test, 5) ? test[5] : "nope"
"nope"
```

which should be more readable.

The `ifelse` evaluates **all** its arguments. The consequence of this behavior is best described by `ifelse` docstring:

> This differs from `?` or `if` in that it is an ordinary function, so all the arguments are evaluated first. In some cases, using `ifelse` instead of an `if` statement can eliminate the branch in generated code and provide higher performance in tight loops.